# segv on exit when reassigning std::clog

Tags: c++, std

I get a segmentation fault after exit with g++ for the following program:

```
#include <iostream>                                                         
#include <fstream>                                                          

int                                                                         
main()                                                                      
    {                                                                       
    std::ofstream logfile( "logfile" ) ;                                    
    if( !logfile.is_open() )                                                
        {                                                                   
        std::cerr << "oops ofstream\n" ;                                    
        return -1 ;                                                         
        }                                                                   
    std::clog.flush() ;                                                     
    std::clog.rdbuf( logfile.rdbuf() ) ;                                    

    std::clog << "test output\n" ;                                          
    std::clog.flush() ;                                                     
    std::cerr << "all done\n" ;                                             

    return 0 ;                                                              
    }
```

Any clue why?

Comment: I'd guess it has something to do with `logfile` getting destroyed when `main()` returns and `clog` getting used and/or destroyed after that.

Comment: Did you try attaching a debugger and looking at the backtrace?

Comment: I did, and the segv happens in a flush in exit_(). I don't get a segv if I change the program save the clog buffer and reassign it back before exit, but I don't understand why.

Comment: `logfile` destroys its buffer on main end. As `clog` now shares its buffer, when it tries to flush its content as part of its own destruction, it accesses destroyed object.

Comment: See, you have the solution! At the end of `main` the logfile and its buffer get destroyed. And then `clog` holds a dangling pointer.

Comment: The reason I care is that I am doing the reassignment of clog down in the depths of a subroutine, and I never plan to send output the the previous clog assignment. Saving the old buffer and then making sure that it is reassigned before exit is very inconvenient and unintuitive. I'd rather clean up the old clog locally.

Comment: @Bo Persson     So the problem is that I had logfile on the stack.  Yay!  solved.

Comment: You can circumvent it by making sure that buffer used by clog is not destroyed before clog. Good luck with that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The lifetime of `std::clog` and friends are managed by a static object of type `std::ios_base::Init` (C++11 27.5.3.1.6 Class ios_base::Init).  When that object is destroyed (after `main()` returns), it performs the following actions being destroying `std::clog` and related `iostream` objects (C++11 27.5.3.1.6/4 Class ios_base::Init):

> calls cout.flush(), cerr.flush(), clog.flush(), wcout.flush(), wcerr.flush(), wclog.flush()

The call to `flush()` will use the `rdbuf()` object in `clog`, and since the `logfile.rdbuf()` passed earlier to `clog` has been destroyed you get undefined behavior.